# SVG on canvas (using fabricjs) can't be seen because of transform: translate rule

Tags: html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

Having a problem with an SVG I'm loading into a canvas using fabric.js
In the screenshot, you'll see the bounding box and the icon not overlapping:
[image]

The issue seems to be coming from the following attribute value in the SVG: `transform="translate(-255.7-577)"`.

I'm having trouble (with fabric.js) figuring out how to adjust the SVG so that this translation is not happening.

Any guidance, either fabric.js specific or just a native canvas method would be appreciated. Can't seem to figure out how to adjust paths in an SVG object.

Comment: We would need your markup in order to provide a real answer, but did you set the viewBox attribute of your svg?

Comment: I didn't create the svg. It's an open source CC0 svg.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure it does also have a markup :-) without it, we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: ;) https://jsfiddle.net/fhgj39rs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabricjs does not have a proper support of transformMatrix as of now.
With every svg you parse the transform attribute from element to parent node get parsed and merged in a single matrix, that is then stored in `object.transformMatrix`.

this `transforMatrix` is correctly handled if you import the objects grouping them:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('mysvg.svg', function(objects, options) { 
    var myobj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.add(myobj ); 
});
```

That would be enough to display it properly.

If for any reason you want them out of the pathgroup object, you have to do an additional step:
1) load svg from url
2) object by object parse the transform matrix attribute with current state of object
3) add object to canvas.

This can be accomplished with this code:

```
fabric.Object.prototype._removeTransformMatrix = function(addTranslate) {

  var left = this.left;
  var top = this.top;

  if (this.type !== 'text' && this.type !== 'i-text') {
    left += this.width / 2;
    top += this.height / 2;
  }

  var matrix = fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(this.transformMatrix ||  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, left, top]);
  var options = fabric.util.qrDecompose(matrix);
  this.scaleX = options.scaleX;
  this.scaleY = options.scaleY;
  this.angle = options.angle;
  this.skewX = options.skewX;
  this.skewY = 0;
  this.flipX = false;
  this.flipY = false;
  var point = new fabric.Point(options.translateX, options.translateY);
  this.setPositionByOrigin(point , 'center', 'center');
  this.transformMatrix = null;
};
```

then calling:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('mysvg.svg', function(objects, options) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      objects[i]._removeTransformMatrix();
      canvas.add(objects[i]); 
    }
});
```

Should do the trick for you.

This will allow you to parse any complex transformation, not only the translate one.
This code assume that coming from an svg the object may have x and y different from 0, but will not carry any angle or skew outside the transform attribute. Also in SVG objects are top-left positioned. This code will not remove any custom transformMatrix of any custom objects in fabricJS environment.

Use latest fabricjs of course. not working with 1.5.0

here fiddle with this code in action.
http://jsfiddle.net/asturur/7gvJG/66/

One of the svg has the translate attribute expressed like this:

```
translate(-x-y);
```

Checking on w3cspesc:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute
it looks like that the space is mandatory:

```
translate:
    "translate" wsp* "(" wsp* number ( comma-wsp number )? wsp* ")"
comma-wsp:
    (wsp+ comma? wsp*) | (comma wsp*)
```

it says

```
"translate"+ 0 or more spaces + "("  + number + optionally a comma-wsp + another number + ")"
```

and comma-wsp is defined as:

```
1 or more spaces, 0 or 1 comma, any number of spaces. OR a comma + any number of spaces.
```

So at least one space or a comma should be there.

**Updated January 15th, 2016 by @onassar**
While the above logic helped, I realized a simpler way was to format the SVG xml that was returned with the following:

```
xml.replace(/translate\((\-?[0-9\.]+)(\-?[0-9\.]+)\)/gi, 'translate($1 $2)')
```

This did the trick, but the above steps will also help if you're looking for another solution.

Comment: A little confused. When I click `Load`, it presents me with the error. However when I press `Load without grouping`, that's when it works. Here is a video showing that: http://screencast.com/t/wXyurPKuz2JH

In my code, I am in fact already loading the SVG via the `groupSVGElements` fabric.util method. Maybe I should be loading it ungroup? Not sure.

Comment: Either group or remove transformatrix with my code. If you can start up a fiddle with svg and base code i will complete it.

Comment: Okay let me try your solution and see how it works. Respond again in a few minutes.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gvJG/64/ As you can see (here: https://i.imgur.com/U1yLK4I.png), the bounding box and image are still off, despite being grouped.

Comment: you have an error in fiddle, missing space between 2 values of translate function. added  working fiddle to answer

Comment: that will be a problem. i'm using an open source library of icons. there are about 150,000 of them, and some of them have their translate values written that way. do you have a recommendation on what to do about that?

Comment: i check the specs on w3c. if space is not mandatory i will not be, if it is, your svg are wrong and i cannot do anything about it

Comment: gotcha. is it possible for fabric to deal with cases where there is no space? i've changed my code with a regex so that if there is no space, add one: `xml.replace(/translate\((\-?[0-9\.]+)(\-?[0-9\.]+)\)/gi, 'translate($1 $2)')` But curious if fabric could have that be part of it.

Comment: No. The codebase is already large and we strive to support standard svgs already, we cannot patch code to accept non standard one.